# Ghostscript error: ERROR -15 closing pdfwrite device

Tags: compiling, ghostscript

Consider the folllowing example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\ifprint
%\printfalse
\printtrue

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
  \ifprint
    \hypersetup{
      pdfauthor={Søhest},
      pdfsubject={Eksamenssæt}
    }
  \else
    \hypersetup{
      pdfauthor={Søhest},
      pdfsubject={Eksamenssæt}
    }
  \fi
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Note: Of course the code in the example is rather pointless since there is no difference between `\printfalse` and `\printtrue` but I have stripped the code as much a possible (I think).

I compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` and get the following error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: ERROR -15 closing pdfwrite device. See gs/psi/ierrors.h for code explanation.
```

I can't figure out how to fix this problem (and a search hasn't given me anything useful).

P.S. I upgraded my system from Fedora 18 to 19 yesterday and the problem started occuring thereafter.

Comment: I see no issues with TL2013 on Windows, which claims the same GhostScript version. What does `which ps2pdf` give you?

Comment: @JosephWright `[<username>@localhost test]$ which ps2pdf
/usr/bin/ps2pdf`

Comment: I cannot reproduce it using TL2013/Linux and gs 9.05. What is the *complete* error message? Which `hyperref` version you are using?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have given the complete output from the terminal. (I have a feeling that it has something to do with Fedora 19.) I use the very latest public `hyperref` version; I updated my TeX Live system an hour ago.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg As before, it would also be handy to have access to the files here: I guess the `dvi` and `ps` would be useful.

Comment: @JosephWright DVI: http://gupl.dk/700605/ ... PS: http://gupl.dk/700606/

Comment: @SvendTveskæg As expected, file converts fine here. I suspect a 'local issue', but I guess we need another Fedora user to check if it's OS-related.

Comment: @JosephWright Okay; thank you, Joseph. (Now, I'm actually rather sure it is a OS-related problem: ``Update CUPS to the latest upstream release and use PDF rather than PostScript as baseline document format.'' from https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/CUPS1.6.)

Comment: I get the error on F19. Can you use `pdflatex` instead?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot It is possible but I would really like to use `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`. Thank you for clearing up that it is a F19 error.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I actually can't use `pdflatex` at all, I see now. `:(`

Comment: Same error here TL13, GS-9.07, Gentoo-Linux.

Comment: @AlexG Also if you use `ps2pdf13`?

Comment: `ps2pdf` is a simple script that runs one of the `ps2pdfXY` scripts (`XY` is 12, 13 or 14) depending on the setting.

Comment: @egreg Okay. For me, `ps2pdf12` and `ps2pdf13` works but `ps2pdf` and `ps2pdf14` don't.

Comment: `ps2pdf13` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine found a very simpel solution: Simply use

```
ps2pdf13
```

instead of

```
ps2pdf
```

and everything is fine (at least for the documents I have tried so far).

**Update**

The error is now fixed but one gets the following message:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: PDFDocEncoding 0 cannot be represented in Unicode
```

I have send a question to the Fedora team and asked what I shuold do about it. (I'll add their answer here if it is relevant.)

**Update 2**

Now, `ps2pdf` is working flawlessly on Fedora when upgrading to the newest version of Ghostscript.